# using the FOR loop to catch multiples of the same number

Tags: java, jsp

I have a String that holds the value of an ID number from a query that I am parsing into an Integer. I need a FOR loop that checks every time a certain number appears in the query more than five times. I am displaying this information on a JSP page. 
So far I have:

```
while (rs1.next()){
            String TicketNumber = rs1.getString("XXXXX_XXXXX_NO");
            String MUID = rs1.getString("XXXXXX_XXXX");
            String Name = rs1.getString("XXXXXXX_XXXXX_NAME");
            String LastName = rs1.getString("XXXXX_XXXX_NAME");
            int PIDM = Integer.parseInt(MUID);
       for ( int n = 0, n >= 5, n += 1 )
```

rs1 is the statement that I am quering and I am setting these values, parsing out the MIUD into PIDM but I am not quite sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make use of the powerful [aggregate functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp) the SQL offers you on that area:

```
SELECT muid, COUNT(muid) AS muid_count FROM ticket GROUP BY muid
```

in combination with

```
Integer muid = resultSet.getInt("muid");
Integer muidCount = resultSet.getInt("muid_count");
```

Or if you're actually interested in the non-aggregated information, then best is indeed to use a `Map<Integer, Integer>` or maybe better `Map<Integer, List<Ticket>>` so that you can just display it in JSP at once nicely using JSTL `c:forEach`. You can then get the size of `List<Ticket>` using JSTL `fn:length`.

E.g.

```
<c:forEach items="${ticketMap}" var="ticketEntry">
    MUID: ${ticketEntry.key}<br>
    Ticket count: ${fn:length(ticketEntry.value)}<br>
    All tickets:<br>
    <c:forEach items="${ticketEntry.value}" var="ticket">
        Number: ${ticket.number}<br>
        Name: ${ticket.name}<br>
        Lastname: ${ticket.lastName}<br>
    </c:forEach>
    <hr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Map to count the number of times each number appears.

```
Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>()
```

Do this for every record in the result set

```
Integer count = map.get(PIDM);
if( count == null )
    map.put(PIDM, 1);
else
    map.put(PIDM, count + 1);
```

Then, after the query is done, loop through looking for a count of 5 or greater

```
for( Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> e : map.entrySet() )
{
    if( e.getValue() > 5 )
    {
        // do something with e.getKey() which is the PIDM from above
    }
}
```